# Мост между asyncio и Торнадо

Tags: python, tornado, asyncio

Хочу использовать **asyncio** в проекте на **Tornado**.

Прочитал [это](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncio.html#module-tornado.platform.asyncio), делаю все точно также, как описано в доках:

```
def make_app():

    settings = {
        'template_path': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        'static_path': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        'cookie_secret': "__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
        'xsrf_cookies': True,
        'debug': True,
    }

    return Application(handlers=[
            url(r"/", IndexPageHandler, name='index'),
            url(r"/logout", LogoutHandler),
            url(r"/websocket", ChatHandler),
            (r'/(favicon\.ico)', StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings['static_path'])),
        ], **settings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(PORT,)
    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
assert not IOLoop.initialized()
AssertionError
```

Если делаю тоже самое в новом скрипте (без `app = make_app()`) и запускаю - то все норм.

Почему так получается и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне подсказали [тут](https://plus.google.com/+STLEON/posts/jGTkNRRWo5S):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()

    app = make_app()

    app.listen(PORT)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```